# Achieve Inheritance/reusing functionality/properties from multiple parents

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, reusability

Note: Before marking it as duplicate or to close, please consider to read the **complete question**, you might rather prefer to suggests an edit than closing it.

**Update** Yes i know c# does not allow multiple inheritance, but off course its some time needed practically as following scenario, so please guide, either why it should not be needed or how it could be achieved

---

I need to inherit/reuse the functionality/members from different classes in one child. I have a class

```
abstract class Hurdle
{       
   public virtual void setPositionInCells(){somecode_sp();}
   public virtual void OnHit(){somecode_h();}
}
```

The real classes i need are `MovableSingleCellHurdle`, `MovableMultiCellHurdle`, `StationarySingleCellHurdle` and  `StationaryMultiCellHurdle`

But in C# i can only do this

```
class SingleCellHurdle: Hurdle
{
 public int CellNumber;
 public override void setPositionInCells(){ base(); somecode_sp1();}
}
class MultipleCellHurdle: Hurdle 
{
 public int[] CellNumbers;
 public override void setPositionInCells(){ base(); somecode_sp2();}
}

class MovableHurdle: Hurdle
{
 public float HitForce;
 public override void OnHit() { base(); somecode_h1();}
}
class StationarHurdle: Hurdle
{
 public override void OnHit() { base(); somecode_h2();}
}
```

But i am stuck to do following

```
class MovableSingleCellHurdle: MovableHurdle, SingleCellHurdle
{
   public override void OnHit() { base();}
   public override void setPositionInCells() { base();}
   public int getLastHitForce()
   {
       return HitForce;
   }
   public int getLastPositionCells()
   {
       return CellNumber;
   }
}
```

**Why i need to do is, that i should not need to duplicate the code of `setPosition()` and `OnHit()` for real classes again**

What currently i am doing is no inheritance/reuse at all because its not allowing me to make my above required structure

I should have learned this years ago, but unfortunately could not find an article/blog which is specially targeting this scenario of inheritance.

If you think this question deserves down-vote, its OK, but please guide me as well. If I am doing it entirely wrong, then pleasde guide what approach I should use? Or what article completely explains handling this scenario using best oop practices

Comment: For a start, C# doesn't allow inheritance from multiple classes. Your `MovableSingleCellHurdle` is invalid then. Also, `base()` is invalid. You probably meant `base.baseMethod()` instead.

Comment: Have you looked at composition as an alternative to inheritance?

Comment: @FacticiusVir, I must have done it due to being poor in that level good concepts of composition/inheritance, can you plz guide where i looked like that or how should i look at that

Comment: I think the main problem here is that your post doesn't read as a question. **What is the question here?**

Comment: @Sami This is a reasonable intro: https://codingdelight.com/tag/composition-over-inheritance/

Answer (score 0):

C# doesn't support multiple inheritance.  One way to do it would be like this:

```
class Hurdle { ... }
class SingleCellHurdle : Hurdle { ... }
class MultipleCellHurdle : Hurdle { ... }
class MovableSingleCellHurdle : SingleCellHurdle { ... }
class MovableMultipleCellHurdle : MultipleCellHurdle { ... }    
class StationarySingleCellHurdle : SingleCellHurdle { ... }
class StationaryMultipleCellHurdle : MultipleCellHurdle { ... }
```

Obviously, this is only practical if you have relatively few classes with such relationships.  It will grow exponentially the more such relationships you have.

Comment: And alternatively I could inherit then like `MovableSingleCellHurdle :  MovableHurdle` and `MovableMultipleCellHurdle :  MovableHurdle`. Yes it's one of the options but feeling so much helplessness

Answer (score 0):

You can't and souldn't use inheritance in this case.

The reason why is based on the LSP ([Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)).

To be more clear about LSP: you **probably** will [break LSP as explained here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem). But that's all just academics. You may ignore or study it based on you mileage.

The solution is most probably delegation.

First, you need a *have-a* relationship between the simpler classes and the richer ones, like this:

```
class MovableSingleCellHurdle
{
    private MovableHurdle mh;
    private SingleCellHurdle sch;
```

Next, you **delegate** any calls to those classes like this:

```
    public void OnHit()
    {
        mh.OnHit();
        // or: sch.OnHit();
    }
```

If a mehtod has parameters, pass them along and if they return something, return it, like this:

```
    public int SumAndFloor(double a, double b)
    {
        return internalDelegateClass.SumAndFloor(a, b);
    }
```

This pattern is called composition, because you compose an object by leveraging simpler objects.

The fact that you call the inner methods is [delegation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forwarding_(object-oriented_programming)).

Furthermore, you want to construct the object with a constructor. This is called [constructor injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Constructor_injection):

```
    public MovableSingleCellHurdle(MovableHurdle mh, SingleCellHurdle sch)
    {
        this.mh = mh;
        this.sch = sch;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think inheritance would break liskov in this case.  I don't see any reason why you couldn't use a more-derived class instance where a less-derived instance is needed, given the information provided.

Comment: Yes, that sounds nice, I would read more about that type of composition with delegates and solve it practically, i hope it is the required answer.

Comment: @rory.ap I agree, there's no indication that LSP is violated. But this reasoning is backwards (we say "what we see does not violate LSP"). The point is you have to prove that LSP is not violated in all cases, but we don't know what all those cases are. That's why I said **probably** and better play it save. To be more precise: we don't know what `somecode_h1()` does. It's possible but not provable that LSP is violated.